# Different Shiny inputs for each Tab - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, quantmod, shiny-reactivity

I have a shiny app with multiple tabs for viewing Stock data that I would like to be able to have different input options for each tab. Currently, there are inputs/filters taking up space on tabs where they have no function. For example, my date range input, sliderinput, and checkbox inputs are not all necessary for viewing my Stock dividend tab. Is there a way I can control what inputs go to each tab?  Here is a general snippet of what my code looks like.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My App"),

  dateRangeInput("daterange", "Select a Time Frame to be Plotted", start = "2007-01-01", end = 
 Sys.Date()),

mainPanel(
 selectInput("stock", "Select a Stock(s):", choices = unique(df$Stock), multiple = TRUE, selected = "AAPL")),

sliderInput(),

checkboxGroupInput(),

tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("Stock Chart", plotlyOutput("line")),
tabPanel("Returns", reactableOutput('returns')),
tabPanel("Buy/Sell", plotlyOutput("buy_sell")),
tabPanel("Dividends", plotlyOutput("dividend")),
tabPanel("Trendline", reactableOutput("trendline")),
tabPanel("Ticker Lookup", DT::dataTableOutput("ticker"))

  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {


My ggplot graphs/table code here:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to enclose your inputs in their respective `tabPanel` for example you can insert a date range input in stock chart tab like this.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My App"),

  dateRangeInput("daterange", "Select a Time Frame to be Plotted", start = "2007-01-01", end = 
 Sys.Date()),

mainPanel(
 selectInput("stock", "Select a Stock(s):", choices = unique(df$Stock), multiple = TRUE, selected = "AAPL")),

sliderInput(),

checkboxGroupInput(),

tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("Stock Chart", dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Select a Time Frame to be Plotted", start = "2007-01-01", end = Sys.Date()), plotlyOutput("line")),
tabPanel("Returns", reactableOutput('returns')),
tabPanel("Buy/Sell", plotlyOutput("buy_sell")),
tabPanel("Dividends", plotlyOutput("dividend")),
tabPanel("Trendline", reactableOutput("trendline")),
tabPanel("Ticker Lookup", DT::dataTableOutput("ticker"))

  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {


My ggplot graphs/table code here:
```

Comment: What if I have a `sidebarLayout()`, and want a different input in the sidebar for each tab. Is that possible?